# Running one Open MPI program from another Open MPI program with different number of processes

Tags: openmpi

Is it possible to run an open mpi program with 4 processes from another open mpi program which is started using 2 processes. For example, I have program1.exe and program2.exe. My goal is to run program1.exe using 2 processes of which 1 process does some work whereas, another process runs another program "program2.exe" with 4 processes. To run program1.exe I use "mpirun -np 2 program1.exe". From within this program I want to run program2.exe as "mpirun -np 4 program2.exe". Is this possible?

Comment: `program1` can `MPI_Comm_spawn()` `program2`.

Comment: Thank you @GillesGouaillardet .. It was helpful.